# How to select first N elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
<div class="nav-top">
<ul>
  <li class="tab1"><a href="/">test</a></li>
  <li class="tab2"><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li class="tab3"><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li class="navahead"><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li class="navahead"><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li class="new"><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i want to only add onmouse over event to the first three li(tab1,tab2,tab3). how to write the if condition.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You don't need an `if` - you can use the jQuery `:lt()` selector

```
$('ul li:lt(3)').mouseenter(function(){});
```

Note that the index is zero-based, so the first three are 0, 1 and 2

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

**Update July 2020:**

As of jQuery 3.4, the `:lt` pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using `.slice()`. For example, `:lt(3)` can be replaced with a call to `.slice(0,3)`

Comment: the question is, what if there are one million `li` elements. would jQuery know only to take the first 3, or does it take all, then slice 3.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you don't need any conditional statement, you can do it with a single selector:

```
$('ul li:first').mouseenter(function() {
});
```

If you want to further "filter" your `<li>` nodes, be more specific, like

```
$('ul li.navahead:first').mouseenter(function() {
});
```

**update**:

To answer your updated question:

```
$('ul li[class^=tab]').mouseenter(function() {
});
```

`^=` will select all classnames which begin with a given string ("tab" in this case)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.slice(startIndex, endIndex)`

```js
$("div").slice(0, 2).remove();
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need "if". Use selectors

```
$("ul li:first")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-child(-n+{TARGET_NUMBER})`

Use `ul li:nth-child(-n+3)` to select first 3 elements.

E.g.

```
$('ul li:nth-child(-n+3)').mouseenter(function() {
    // your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.tab1, li.tab2, li.tab3").mouseover(function(){
    // write your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be like:

```
 $(".tab1").mouseover(function() {

});
```